# How to manipulate ts configuration into a brand new extension in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I follow the official guide to create a new extension on TYPO3 7.6 based on an old extension that need configuration static and configuration in template but in controller, I can't get the config.

```
$this->settings
```

return an empty array

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf'][strtolower($this->extensionName)]
```

return an empty array

```
$TYPO3_LOADED_EXT[strtolower($this->extensionName)]
```

return an empty array

does somebody know how to manipulate configuration in TYPO3 7.6?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custome extension `setup.ts` and `constant.ts` like this.

**setup.ts**

```
plugin.tx_yourextension_key {   
    settings {
        enableWebsiteField = {$plugin.tx_extension_key.settings.enableWebsiteField}
}
```

**constant.ts**

```
 plugin.tx_yourextension_key {  
       settings {
        enableWebsiteField = 1
 }
```

You can get value in `controller.php` file like this.

```
$this->settings['enableWebsiteField']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it

Comment: That was it! Thank you